# Is there a way to edit image alt-tags in Magento2 by looking at all the images on the site in one place?

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to edit image alt-tags in Magento2 by looking at all the images on the site in one place? Instead of going into each content block or page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**In Magento 2 Phtml file controls img alt for the front-end**

**For Product Gallery Image at Frontend** :

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/gallery.phtml
```

**For Product Image at Frontend** :

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image.phtml
```

Comment: For admin block images?

Comment: @Shiwani please explain in brief what you need

Comment: Instead of going into each content block or page, I need to edit image alt-tags. Is there a way?

Comment: Anyone have suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can export all products as CSV, you can go through and edit base_image_label to change them in bulk, then import updates